# Viewport on mobile

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

I have created a website that has an outer wrapper that is responsive to 960px then everything inside the container is fixed with (not responsive).

Problem is when viewed on mobile i get a large site because i have min-width container of 960px;

Is this a viewport issue i need to fix or add?

Fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6LgwF/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" />

    <div class="container"

<h1>Welcome</h1><br />
My container is actually 960px only change it  to 560 for demo
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1440px;
    min-width:960px;
    background:grey;
}

.container{
    width:560px;
    background:pink;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    background: grey;
}

.container{
    max-width: 560px;
    background: pink;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So I removed the min-width from the .wrapper, added a max-width of 560px foe the .container.

Hope that fixes your issue.